# Alignment of layout elements change when using horizontal linear layout manager in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-layout

I am basically trying to create a recycler view that has a linear layout manager with a horizontal scrolling. When I was using a linear layout manager with vertical scrolling, the design of the recycler view rows was properly aligned as per provided in the layout file but the design elements gets placed in completely weird places when I am using horizontal scrolling[image] 
[image]
Here is my code for the recycler view row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shop_product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_selected" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@color/black80"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="1200 INR"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/black80">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_product_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="The Indian Shop"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="150 likes"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout file for the activity layout is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.paaltao.activity.MyShopActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/product_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            >

            <RelativeLayout

                android:id="@+id/shop_cover_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_cover_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/shop_cover_image"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/apple_small" />



            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shop_start_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/product_first_launch_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shop_cover_area"
                >


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_products_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"


                    />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>





        <com.paaltao.classes.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/lightGreen"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity code is as follows :

```
package com.paaltao.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.paaltao.Adapters.ShopProductAdapter;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.classes.AddFloatingActionButton;
import com.paaltao.classes.Product;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyShopActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_shop);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.shop_products_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ShopProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData()));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.setTitle("Shop");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        AddFloatingActionButton addProductButton = (AddFloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions1);
        addProductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Tag","Clicked");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyShopActivity.this, AddProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public static List<Product> getData(){
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.apple_small,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.bag_icon,R.drawable.notify_icon,R.drawable.apple_small,
                R.drawable.bag_icon,R.drawable.apple_small,R.drawable.notify_icon,R.drawable.apple_small,R.drawable.ic_launcher};

        String[] product_name = {"Handmade","Photography","Electronics","Electronics","Electronics","Electronics","Electronics",
                "Electronics","Electronics","Electronics"};

        for(int i=0;  i<icons.length && i< product_name.length;i++){
            Product current = new Product();
            current.setProduct_name(product_name[i]);
            current.setProduct_id(icons[i]);
            data.add(current);
        }

        return data;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_shop, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I use vertical orientation in recycled view the design works fine. The problem only occurs when I set the orientation to LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very foolish of me to ask such a question :P

In the layout containing the design of recycler view row, The width and height cannot be set as "match parent". Instead the thing works simply for "wrap content". To enable horizontal scrolling the row must be given fixed width and height.